# Find the Fourier series without using normal integration formulas.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the step function:

$f(x) =\begin{cases} 
      -1 & -\pi < x < 0 \\
      1 & 0 < x < \pi 
   \end{cases} =\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}
$

Using the aforementioned series, find the Fourier series for:

$f(x) =\begin{cases} 
      0 & -c < x < 0 \\
      1 & 0 < x < c 
   \end{cases}
$

So, what I did was apply the adapted interval format and changed the argument of $\sin$ to $\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{c}$ and then took the average of the series because the function shifted from -1 to 0. Giving me,

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{c})}{2n-1}$

So, I think this is correct, although I am still rather unsure if the logic is sound. However, then the question goes on to ask me to find the Fourier series for,

$f(x) = |x|$

Mind you, this is all still part of the same problem, so I imagine that I would need to adapt my answer for the step function somehow, but I have no idea where to begin. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach for the first part looks fine. For the second one, to get the Fourier series of $f(x) = |x|$, first see if you can figure out the Fourier series for $f'(x) = ?$. After that, you can just integrate the series term by term.

Comment: So, when you say find the Fourier series of $f^{'}(x)$, you mean $f^{'}(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}$, yes?

Comment: Hint: $|x|= xf(x)$. f(x) as you have defined it is not the standard definition of the Heaviside step function, it's the sign function.

Comment: @Austin Yes. If you don't see what the problem wanted you to do yet, try writing $\tfrac{|x|}{x}$ as a piecewise function and see if you already know its Fourier series.

Comment: Okay, so I believe I see now. $\frac{|x|}{x}$ as a piecewise function is $-1$ from $-\infty < x < 0$ and $1$ from $0<x< \infty$. The Fourier series is already given, but the limits aren't quite right. So, then I suspect I would basically just need to integrate each term in the series.